# Using a capital letter at the start of a French surname in written English

Tags: capitalization, french, surnames

To mention, in English, the French mathematician Guillaume de l'Hôpital only by his surname, should I write *De l'Hôpital* or *de l'Hôpital*? Should I use some other combination?

I would use the reference that one answer to [Using English naming customs for foreign names](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189609/using-english-naming-customs-for-foreign-names) suggests, but it is not an open source and this specific question is not answered there.

Comment: Going by the Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillaume_de_l%27H%C3%B4pital), "*de*" is omitted and "*l'Hôpital*" is capitalized only when it's at the start of the sentence.

Comment: Very closely related: [Initial capitalization of foreign surnames when starting a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/185852/191178). This question covers *de* and other Dutch name parts but doesn't address *l'*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initial capitalization of foreign surnames when starting a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185852/initial-capitalization-of-foreign-surnames-when-starting-a-sentence)

Comment: @EllieKesselman No, but thank you.

Comment: Are you interested exclusively in French surnames or foreign surnames in general?

Comment: I was interested in the case "de l'" in French.

Comment: I will add a tag to indicate that. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

About multipart names, [Prof. Paul Brians of Washington State University](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/25/multipart-names/) says:

> In many European languages family names are often preceded by a preposition (***de***, da, di, von, and van all mean “of”), an article (le and la mean “the”) or both (du, des, del, de la, della and van der all mean “***of the***”).
>
> In their original languages the two parts of the name are usually separated by a space, and ***the prefixed preposition or article is not capitalized unless it begins a sentence***. If you take a college course involving famous European names you will be expected to follow this pattern. It’s not “De Beauvoir” but “***de Beauvoir***”; not “Van Gogh” but “***van Gogh***.” The only exception is when the name begins a sentence:
>
> - ***De Gaulle*** led the Free French
>
> but
>
> - ***Charles de Gaulle*** had a big nose.

Quoting Mark Stevens, the director of general reference at *Merriam-Webster’s*, [Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2010/07/nobiliary-particle.html) says:

> In the names of Frenchmen and -women, ***de*** and ***d’*** are almost always lowercased; treatment of ***du*** varies. ***La*** and ***Le*** are almost always capitalized.

---

With Guillaume de l'Hôpital, the difficulty is whether to mention the surname including or omitting ***de***. The internet uses more than one variant at the beginning of a sentence, but most sites omit the ***de***, and capitalise ***L***:

> - L'Hôpital ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillaume_de_l%27H%C3%B4pital)) and ([Lcalculus](https://www.larsoncalculus.com/etf6/content/biographies/lhopital-guillaume/))
> - De l'Hôpital ([mathshistory](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/De_LHopital/))

Since all mathematicians speak about ***[L'Hôpital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)***, also spelled as ***L'Hospital's rule***, I would go for ***L'Hôpital***, whether it is at the beginning or in the middle of the sentence.

Comment: A possible exception is when **of** is shortened to **O'**, for example *John of Gaunt* to *John O'Gaunt*.

Comment: Yes, correct, but we are speaking here about the particular case of the French _de l'_.

Comment: Sorry: your examples mention *de* and *d'* (Charles de Gaulle), and "the prefixed preposition or article is not capitalized unless it begins a sentence".

Comment: So, according to the last reference, it should be *de L'Hôpital* because *de* is not capitalized but *Le* is and it is in the contracted form, right?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Basically, most people omit the _**de**_ and then _**L'Hôpital**_ falls under the capitalisation of "L" rule.